# How to differentiate between 1 space and 3 spaces

Tags: c, string, scanf, strtok

I'm trying to write a C program for a morse code decoder. The format of this code is written in a way so that letters are separated by 1 space and words are separated by 3 spaces ie.

-(1  space).-  = EA
-(3 spaces).- = E A

```
- .-   = EA
-   .- = E A
```

I'm currently using fscanf to read each set of letters but it is removing all the spaces. I found that I could use fgets then strtok to separate the letters themselves however strtok will not differentiate between 1 space and 3. I guess my questions are: is there a function that can differentiate between 1 and 3 spaces, or is there just an overall better way of thinking about this.

Comment: Just iterate over the fgets result char-by-char?

Comment: `fgets` + char-by-char iteration should do what you want; you just have to code it.

Comment: You have to iterate and count them. How else would you do it?

Comment: `if( str[i] == ' ' && str[i+1] == ' ' )` True when you've got two in the headlights... Not hard... (Elaboration of this proposal is left as an exercise for the reader.)

Comment: Or, you can use `fgetc()` and keep a count of when you may be in a field of multiple spaces... It's not hard... Be creative, and turn your back on `scanf()`...

Comment: Or, `strtok()` is returning pointers into the string that you're dissecting... You could use "pointer arithmetic" to calculate how much strtok() left on the floor between segments... It's not hard... Be creative!

Comment: Using `fscanf()` is probably the wrong tool. It would require rather subtle format strings to be able to distinguish between the two scenarios. You'd presumably have to use a length-limited scan set `%3[ ]` to pick up 1-3 spaces, after you'd used `%8[-.]` (Wikipedia on [Morse Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code) indicates that the maximum length for a Morse code point is 5 for letters and digits, but punctuation seems to use 5 or 6, and the error mark is 8 dots; it also says spacing is 1, 3, 7 between marks, letter, words) to pick up the dots and dashes. Remember to allow for nulls.

Comment: *is there a function that can differentiate between 1 and 3 spaces* No, not directly.  I think no matter what you do, you're pretty much going to have to inspect and count individual characters, by hand, yourself.  In C, `char *` pointers and pointer arithmetic make this straightforward, although it can be somewhat tedious and error-prone.  Make sure you test your code on lots of cases, and if possible it's a good idea to construct some kind of automated test suite, so that whenever you make a change to your code to handle one case better, you can quickly make sure you haven't broken anything.

Answer (score 0):

As I noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74001677/how-to-differentiate-between-1-space-and-3-spaces#comment130662502_74001677), using `fscanf()` is probably the wrong tool. It requires subtle format strings to distinguish between one space and three spaces — in general, `scanf()` is cavalier about skipping over spaces. You have to use a length-limited scan set `%3[ ]` to pick up 1-3 spaces, after using `%8[-.]` to detect the symbol.

Wikipedia on [Morse Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code) indicates that the maximum length for a Morse code point is 5 for letters and digits, but punctuation seems to use 5 or 6 (and 7 for the `$`), and the error mark is 8 dots.

This code reads from standard input and identifies the symbols and word spaces correctly.  It assumes that the end of a line also marks the end of a word.  It also makes allowance for people to make mistakes in the data by allowing up to 15 dots and dashes in a symbol, and up to 15 spaces between symbols.  It doesn't diagnose invalid symbols but does report if the spacing
is wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void decode_morse(const char *buffer)
{
    char symbol[16];
    char spaces[16];

    printf("Input:  [%s]\n", buffer);
    int offset = 0;
    int nbytes;
    int rc;
    while ((rc = sscanf(buffer + offset, "%15[-.]%15[ ]%n", symbol, spaces, &nbytes)) > 0)
    {
        printf("Symbol: [%s]", symbol);
        if (rc == 2)
        {
            size_t length = strlen(spaces);
            if (length == 3 || buffer[offset + nbytes] == '\0')
                printf(" EOW");
            else if (length != 1)
                printf(" Bogus spacing (length = %zu)", length);
            putchar('\n');
            offset += nbytes;
        }
        else
        {
            if (rc == 1)
                printf(" EOW");
            putchar('\n');
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[1024];

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != 0)
    {
        buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0';
        decode_morse(buffer);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The Morse for "this is the end of the day" is, I believe:

```
- .... .. ...   .. ...   - .... .   . -. -..   --- ..-.   - .... .   -.. .- -.--
```

The output from the program given that as a line of input is:

```
Input:  [- .... .. ...   .. ...   - .... .   . -. -..   --- ..-.   - .... .   -.. .- -.--]
Symbol: [-]
Symbol: [....]
Symbol: [..]
Symbol: [...] EOW
Symbol: [..]
Symbol: [...] EOW
Symbol: [-]
Symbol: [....]
Symbol: [.] EOW
Symbol: [.]
Symbol: [-.]
Symbol: [-..] EOW
Symbol: [---]
Symbol: [..-.] EOW
Symbol: [-]
Symbol: [....]
Symbol: [.] EOW
Symbol: [-..]
Symbol: [.-]
Symbol: [-.--] EOW
```